# Neovim QuickFix command like VSCode

Tags: neovim

I'm testing the Neovim (Astrovim), and I've moved from VSCode

I had a shortcut **ctrl + .** that if the line had any missing import, it auto imports for me

Someone knows how to get it working in Astrovim?

I read the docs of Astrovim and didn't found a related hotkey for it.

If someone knows a Plugin or a "Native" function in Astrovim, let me know

Answer (score 0):

It's called code actions and comes as part of LSP(https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html). The shortcut for LSP code-actions in AstorVim is `<Space>la`.

For it to work you need to install LSP first for your programming language. for typescript, it goes something like this `:LspInstall typescript`

[image]

**Useful links from AstroVim documentation**

1. https://docs.astronvim.com/#-setup
2. https://docs.astronvim.com/basic-usage/mappings/#lsp-mappings